# Erlang: DRYing up string+binary concatenation

Tags: string, erlang

I am currently forming strings from strings and binaries like this:

```
X = string:join(io_lib:format("~s~s~s", ["something1", "something2",<<"something3">>]), "") %X is now something1something2something3
```

This seems painful and messy. Because in order to dry this up with another such string with a different number of "~n":

```
Y = string:join(io_lib:format("~s~s", ["something1", <<"something2">>]), "")
```

I essentially have to write a function that counts the size of the argument list, and forms `~n[that many times]` and plugs it into this.

Is there a better way to be doing this?

`Eshell V8.0.2  (abort with ^G)
1> F = <<"asdf">>,
1> string:join(io_lib:format("~s~s~s", ["something1", "something2", F]),"").
"something1something2asdf"
2> lists:flatten(["something1", "something2", F]).
[115,111,109,101,116,104,105,110,103,49,115,111,109,101,116,
 104,105,110,103,50,<<"asdf">>]
3>`

Comment: Why are you formatting the strings at all instead of just joining them together?

Comment: @JustinNiessner sorry I left out a crucial detail, my bad. That's what I get for trying to produce a MWE.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another possible solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you need the call to `io_lib:format` at all. It's not doing any work in this case.

```
string:join(["something1","something2","something3"], "").
```

Would give you the same result. You can simplify even further if there's really no separator character (and taking advantage of the fact that strings are just lists in Erlang):

```
lists:flatten(["something1", "something2", "something3"]).
```

**Update**

I see now that you're working with a list of different data types. While a one-liner may look pretty, you can see that they're not always flexible. In your case, I would create some mapper functions to handle mapping different types to strings. Maybe something like:

```
-module(string_utils).
-export([concat/1]).

to_string(Value) when is_binary(Value) -> binary_to_list(Value);
to_string(Value) -> Value.
concat(List) ->
  lists:flatten(lists:map(fun to_string/1, List)).
```

And then your calling code would be:

```
string_utils:concat(["something1", "something2", <<"something3">>]).
```

Comment: sorry I edited my question. Some of my list elements were binaries.